# Checkpoint - Automatic NAT

Tags: checkpoint

I have a checkpoint firewall (R75, Splat) that has a server published with Automatic NAT enabled, however I'm unable to connect to external websites.

Traffic leaves the firewall ok but the Internet router is ARPing to find the MAC address for the published server. This results in return traffic from the websites to never reach the firewall.

Any thoughts as to why that would be occurring, in TCPDump I dont see the firewall responding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurred because the external interface was not responding to ARP requests from the upstream router.

Setting an appropriate routing entry resolved the problem.